# How could I mimic a Kafka consumer missing consuming a message in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there an elegant way to test this - I have a Kafka Broker set up with two partitions and have a producer publish to both partitions (random).
I have two consumers running with random sleep in between as threads and one is set to autooffset earliest and the other set to latest.

I am trying to mimic a scenario when the consumer set to latest will miss a message sent by the producer. And if this happens is there a way i can force the second consumer (earliest) to pick up that specific message missed instead of consuming the latest message ?
And / or the first consumer (instead of being restarted) can be forced to find the offset that it missed?

Comment: If the consumer is set to latest, then the producer starts, that means the consumer wouldn't miss the message. On the other side, starting from earliest will always pick up a message written to the broker, but that would take forever for a large topic, so why not seek the consumer to the specific offset where the producer callback says it wrote the record? Follow up question: how are you defining "missed" and is it different than "committed offsets", and do you care about processing same record more than once between your two consumers?

Comment: Thanks for the response OneCricketeer - fundamentally i wanted to test a scenario if the message is not in committed state - and i don't see the consumer having consumed the message but has consumed a more recent message - i am trying to create a scenario like this - not sure if possible....